# selection object as callback parameter

Tags: jquery-select2, jquery-select2-4

I'm trying to use the select2 jquery plugin, and in order to format the result I found out the *templateResult* option, to be used like this:

```
$(".my-select").select2({
    templateResult: function (obj) {
        //templating
    }
});
```

I'd like to know the structure and the methods of that object that the callback accepts as a parameter, but I haven't been able to find any documentation about it.

How does it work?

Answer (score 2):

The object parameters that are passed into functions like `templateResult` and `templateSelection` are referred to as the *data objects*. These are the internal representations of an `<option>` tag, as constructed by Select2.

---

In the case of a `<select>` with `<option>` and/or `<optgroup>` tags (no special data adapters), the object will have the following automatically generated properties

- `id` (optional): The `value` attribute on the `<option>` tag (or the text if there is no `value`). This is not present on `<optgroup>` tags, as they cannot be selected.
- `text`: The text contained within the `<option>` tag, or the `label` attribute of the `<optgroup>`.
- `element`: The DOM element representing the `<option>` or `<optgroup>` tag, which can be used to retrieve attributes on the element (using jQuery or vanilla JavaScript).
- `children` (optional): Any nested `<option>` tags, used when the data object is representing an `<optgroup>`.

For a Select2 instance initialized with the `data` object, which should be an array of options, each data object will match the data objects that were passed in through the array. Additionally, they will have an `element` property that references the automatically-generated `<option>` that Select2 uses to manage it.

When Select2 is used with a remote data source such as AJAX, data objects similar to this (possibly with additional data) are expected to be passed back. These objects will be normalized (`text` and `id` are forced to strings) and passed into the templating functions as they normally would be.

---

These same data objects are what is passed back through the `select2:select`, `select2:unselect`, and related DOM events which allow for you to reference the data object that was selected or unselected.